# Android Studio OutOfMemory Crash

Tags: java, android, bitmap, crash, out-of-memory

My app works totally fine on my phone.
However on a friends phone (Samsung Galaxy S6) it crashes after i change the to a specific Activity. I read on other posts that it has to do something with the Bitmaps. The answers always provided some sort of code to fix the OOM Error. I don't create Bitmaps/Images in my code so I don't know where to put code to fix the Error.

I loaded my ImageButtons like this:

1. Go to the xml file of an Acitivity
2. Place an ImageButton somewhere
3. Use the Design tap of the xml file and change the background to the Image I would like
4. Go into the java file of the same Activity and declare that Button via: `ImageButton name;`
5. In the onCreate function I wrote `name = findViewById(R.id.backButton);`
6. Connect the backButton method with the android:onClick attribute in xml
7. Do that for every ImageButton

I also tried to add the `android:hardwareAccelerated = "false"` and `android:largeHeap = "true"` into the AndroidManifest.xml file. But that didn't solve the Problem.
In one Activity (the one that crashes) I have 6 ImageButtons (3 are visible 3 are invisible). Could the problem be connected with 6 ImageButtons in one Activity? Is that too much for android to handle at the same time. Although three of them are invisible? I also looked into the Profiler of Android Studio. The first Activity uses 122,4 MB of Memory. Second one uses 185,1 MB. As soon as i switch to the "crash" Activity I get a Memory peak with 508,7 MB (Java takes 452MB Memory for that). Is that too much for older devices? How can I improve the Java Memory then?
My Images are in the: app/src/main/res/drawable folder.

---

Edit:
Lets say we have an empty Activity with just a Button (not ImageButton). If I press the Button we go to an Activity where 8 ImageButtons are placed. All of theses Buttons have an Image as their background attribute in their xml file. Are all Images of the ImageButtons loaded into Memory if I start my App and I don't press the first Button? Or are they loaded as soon as I press the Button and go to the Activity?

Here is the Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.howdareyou.testapp, PID: 8276
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 67108876 byte allocation with 4189728 free bytes and 56MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:854)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4175)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:150)
        at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:84)
        at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:80)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:73)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:69)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:207)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:123)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.howdareyou.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off-  different models of phones have different amounts of memory and different allowable heap settings.  So you should expect that apps will crash on different devices at different places due to OOM.  Decide on a minimum hardware spec you want to support, and test on a device of that nature.  If it passes that, you're good.

Secondly-  you have a MB allocation.  That is HUGE.  Most devices will have problems with that.  That's a 4Kx4K bitmap.  You should not be using an image that large.  Especially on a 6 year old phone that will never work.  Find a way to shrink the image and scale it appropriately when you download it or add it to the app, not just at runtime (which is very inefficient memory wise for such a large image).

As for how much memory you get on older devices-  I would expect to start seeing crashes when you cross 100 MB of heap.  I remember a past app I wrote where we eliminated devices that had a hard heap limit of 96 MB, a 2015 device would have been around or even older than that device.  500 MB is so large I'm surprised it runs on even modern devices.  Your memory numbers are enormous, what the heck are you doing?  Firefox with a half dozen tabs comes in under 200 MB.  The Android OS is only 700.

Comment: Thats a good question. I guess its because my java skills are not the best. I had Java in school for 3 years. This is my first App. Its not a small project. I guess most of the problems with Memory and everything else comes from my lack of experience. To put it short: Bad Programming.

Comment: Obviously I can't help much because I don't have the code, but I'd look closely at the sizes of images in your app and how big they need to be.  a 4Kx4K image is so big I don't know of any device that has that screen size.  And with an imageButton-  the image really only needs to be as big as the button, which is probably a few hundred pixels max in each dimension.  To give you an idea of the magnitude of difference, a 4Kx4K images is 64 MB.  a 400 by 400 is 640 KB.  Its ok to be slightly oversize and shrink down, but you should aim to be within 20% or so of the size you actually need.

Comment: I can give you some ideas: 6 Image Buttons on MainActivity. All of them are the same resolution: 1024 x 1024. They obviously are not that big in the App but I wanted to have sharp Images that don't look blurry. I also have pictures with text on them if the resolution is small the text is kinda blurry on different devices.

Comment: Keeping them 1024x1024 won't stop them from being blurry-  it's still going to have to lose fidelity when it shrinks it, its just going to do that at runtime.  Your best bet to make images look good is to put them in at the size you actually want them, so you can check if they're blurry ahead of time (although if you have to choose between shrinking and scaling slightly, yes shrinking has fewer issues).

Comment: Got it. Reduce image sizes will improve Memory a little bit.

Answer (score -1):

Use Glide/Picasso to load images in the activity.here is the example code of Glide library

```
Glide.with(context).load(list.get(position))
            .thumbnail(0.5f).fitCenter()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .into(new CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                    holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                }
            });
```